# How to aggregate and set the size of scatter chart dc.js

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I am working on scatter charts in dc.js. I have couple of questions.

1. How do I aggregate similar data points in a scatter chart ?
2. How do I make the dot size be dynamic based on y axis ?

Comment: Wasn't you able to find something on google search? What have you tried so far? is it dc.js d3.js or  crossfilter jus to be specific? because your question is tagget with d3, dc and crossfilter? and you question ask about dc.js

Comment: I removed the extra tags - generally you want to use the most specific tags for your question. Otherwise you'll just attract unwanted attention from people who don't know what you're talking about. (And often downvotes.)

Comment: Typically when using `dc.scatterPlot` the key for your crossfilter dimension & group will be the coordinates, so aggregation should be taken care of. (E.g. you'll get value:2, value:3 etc.) For your second question, do you mean that you want the dots to be bigger when the Y domain is smaller, and vice versa?

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ my apologies I shouldn't have added d3.js as part of the tag. This one is with respect to dc.js

Comment: @Gordon Second question, I want to show the dot size relative to the y-axis value. Again for first one, when there are two points at the co-ordinates (x,y) i just want y to aggregate and show that as a higher value (EG: (1,5) if this repeats twice I want to show this as 10 at 1 (1,10)). In case if this fails I want to try the second one where I should be able to size the dot based on the number of dots at the same location (EG : (1,5) repeats twice i want to show bigger dot at (1,5) since it appears twice)

Comment: I think you may be looking for the [bubbleChart](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.bubbleChart.html) which supports both of these use cases better. A scatter plot typically has more than dot per X value. Controlling scatter symbol size [is an open issue](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1205) and I think it would require a `pretransition` hook right now.

Comment: (and yeah, it's weird that there are two charts with such closely overlapping functionality. there have been a lot of contributors over the years, with different objectives.)